# How to run `git clone` in docker file?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have specified a `git clone` command in the docker file as below.

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/zhaoyi0113/test.git
```

but I got this error when build the docker image:

```
Cloning into 'test'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

I wonder why it doesn't work. I am able to run this command on my host. Is there anything different if I list it on docker file?

Comment: In general you'd want to run this in the build environment outside your Dockerfile if possible.  Two reasons for that: if the repository is private it's very hard to not leak the credentials you need to clone it, and because of `docker build` caching if the repository updates you won't actually get updated code in your image.

Answer (score 8):

You can pass credentials as arguments to container. This should work

```
FROM alpine:3.8

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash git openssh

ARG username
ARG password

RUN git clone https://${username}:${password}@github.com/username/repository.git

ENTRYPOINT ["sleep 10"]
```

but it might be unsafe if you want to distribute that image

then build

```
docker build \
    --no-cache \
    -t git-app:latest \
    --build-arg username=user \
    --build-arg password=qwerty \
    .
```

Comment: This no longer works, as far as I know. Password authentication is now disabled. ([Source](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/))

Answer (score 0):

I know what wrong with this problem. The issue is because the repo I am cloning is a private repo which means it requires credential to connect to github. Fixing it by passing credentials to the container.

Comment: This way you will leak the credentials to anyone who will pull this image

Comment: You are right. I believe there are some solutions to solve this security issue such as using `ssh-agent` then remove the layer from docker.